# Android Animation show view from left to right

Tags: android, animation, slide

I am trying to change a view's status from invisible to visible, and I also want to have animation that show it from left to right (not moving).

The example that I did in jquery:

```
$(".slide").animate({width:'toggle'},3000);
```

[Javascript EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/smdtfkq8/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily, need to change visibility of the text, you could cover the view with another and then animate the overlapping go from Visible to Gone:

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private View coverView;
    private TextView txtText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        coverView = findViewById(R.id.coverView);
        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
        coverView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                move();
            }
        });
    }

    private void move() {

        //Load animation
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.text_translate);
        //Know when it ends to change visibility
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                coverView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        coverView.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

Layout xml (main_activity.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtText"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="testtestetstesttest" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/coverView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Animation XML.(Located in res/anim) text_translate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="240" >

</translate>
```

You will have to play around with other things like background. If what you want is just use TextView and translated it, use a negative value in "fromDeltaX" and 0 for "toDeltaX". However, the results will not look like in your link.

References 
[Android Developers: Adding Animations](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html)